# Geometry library for C++

Tags: library, c++, math

Is there a simple geometry library for C++?

Just classes for points and lines, and the most basic and common functions such as getting the line length via Pythagorean theorem, calculating the intersection point of 2 lines, checking if 2 lines are parallel, things like that.

Bonus points if it is just a header and source file so I can include it directly into projects without building it separately.

Old Stack Overflow question for reference: [Geometry library in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149392/geometry-library-in-c).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Cairo libraries](http://cairographics.org/),

They may not be the easiest around, but they sure are enstablished. Inkscape and many other top notch projects use them. They also provide font rendering and a lot of other stuff.

They [were proposed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3888.pdf) to become part of the standard library in the next iteration of ISO C++.

Not sure if that proposal went through, but you get the idea of how interoperable and well built those libraries are.

Comment: I see Cairo is for drawing graphics. I just want to clarify that my question was about the computational part. Such a library could be used by programs that read a bunch of coordinates from a text file and store the results in a text file.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want.

`Boost` has two geometry libraries, `boost::geometry` which is not robust but has advanced stuff like non-euclidean geometry (such as latitude/longitude on the Earth) and `boost::polygon` which is robust but doesn't have as many features.

`CGAL` is another popular one, which is also very robust but can sometimes be very slow. CGAL has a lot of algorithms but its heavy template style may not be considered "simple" depending on your use-case. Furthermore, some parts of CGAL use the more strict GPL license (as opposed to LGPL), which some people may find problematic for a library. There is a commercial version you can pay for to work around those limitations.

`Wykobi` is less popular but still very good. It is not robust.

Robust libraries always provide things like topological guarantees, exact predicates etc. Non-robust libraries are usually faster but may produce geometrically or topologically incorrect results in some situations.

Comment: Where did you find non-free software in CGAL?

Comment: @MarcGlisse Thanks for pointing out that CGAL doesn't have non-free software, it is just dual licensed. I have updated my answer to clarify it.